# Business Data Connectivity Model collection property

Tags: sharepoint-server, bcs, bdc, bdc-model

Is it possible to have a collection property in a BDC model?

I added a property to my model class like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<String> MyCollectionProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And I also added it to my bdcm file like this:

```
<TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]" Name="MyCollectionProperty" IsCollection="true">
  <TypeDescriptors>
    <TypeDescriptor Name="TypeDescriptor" TypeName="System.String" />
  </TypeDescriptors>
</TypeDescriptor>
```

But then I'm getting a following error while crawling:

`Error while crawling LOB contents. ( Error caused by exception: System.InvalidOperationException There is an error in XML document (...))`